# Change color of dataLables in ApexChart in React.js

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[ApexChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTHpc.png)

The text on the stack bar chart is coming in white color, I want to change it into a different one and I cant find the exact property for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to have the labels be red for example:

```
dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      enabledOnSeries: undefined,
      formatter: function (val, opts) {
        return val;
      },
      style: {
        fontSize: "14px",
        fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        colors: ["#FF0000"]
      }
    },
```

Comment: @GarimaSinghRajpoot, good to hear.  If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your option with dataLabels and under chart color option.

```
    let options = {
      *dataLabels: {
        style: {
          colors: ['#F44336', '#E91E63', '#9C27B0']
        }
      },*
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        heigth: '200px',
        *color: '#ff0000'*
      },
....
```

Comment: This too Worked. Thank you!